# Simple login connected to MySQL - whats wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, passwords

I looked on http://www.phpportalen.net/wiki/index.php?page=Enkel+inloggning+med+MySql+och+sessioner to how to do a simple login.

But when i try to login now it says that the username or password is wrong. So Im guessing something is not right in my control dokument, where im checking the usernamne and password to the database.

In the exampel i looked on they have it all in the same page, so im guessing I need to change more than i thougt.

This is the code in the loginside:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="stylesheet.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
            if(isset($_GET['badlogin'])){
                echo "Fel användarnamn eller lösenord, försök igen!";
            }
        ?>
            <form method="post" action="check.php">
            <p>User</p>
            <input name="user" type="text" />
            <p>Password</p>
            <input name="password" type="text" />
            <input name="logIn" type="submit" value="Log in" />
            </form>
        <?php
        }
        else{
            header("Location: admin.php");
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code in my controlside:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
function db_escape($post){
    if(is_string($post)){
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $post = stripslashes($post);
        }
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($post);
    }
    foreach($post as $key => $val){
        $post[$key] = db_escape($val);
    }
    return $post;
}
if(isset($_POST["logIn"])){
    // Connect to db
    $dbConn = mysqli_connect("localhost","sabe0011","lösen","sabe0011");
    $dbConn->set_charset("utf8");

    // Check connection
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($dbConn)){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $_POST = db_escape($_POST);
    $checkUserSQL = mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User ='{$_POST['user']}' AND Password ='{$_POST['password']}'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkUserSQL) == 0){
        header("Location: login.php?badlogin=");
        exit;
    }

    $_SESSION['sess_id'] = mysqli_store_result($checkUsersSQL, 0);
    $_SESSION['sess_user'] = $_POST['user'];
    header("Location: admin.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters in your query should be escaped like:

```
$checkUserSQL = mysqli_query($dbConn, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User =" . $_POST['user'] . " AND Password = " . $_POST['password']);
```

But in term of security, you have to see at [the prepared query here](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: I tried that now, but it still dosen't work =/ Do you se anything else?

Comment: You should try your query `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE User = "youruser" AND Password = "yourpassword"` directly in your database

Comment: I tried that and im using the right user and password.. sadly it dosn't seem that easy solved

Comment: If the query work on the database, you should check the variable `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`

Comment: No names of anything is spell wrong, i check that 10 times before i event wrote here, nothing else you see thats wrong? something in the code, more than the names of things?

Comment: Make a `var_dump` before the `mysqli_query` on the `$_POST` variable because you use the `stripslashes` only if the magic quotes are activated and you didn't posted your php configuration. From the documentation: [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). _"This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0."_

Comment: Im sorry but i dont know what you mean? make a var_dump? can you plz write the code you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry , I thought it was obvious. `var_dump($_POST);` just after `$_POST = db_escape($_POST);`. [Here is the documentation](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).